# Prototype Javascript Framework - Fetching PHP response

Tags: php, javascript, response, prototypejs

So I am using Prototype JavaScript Framework, I have no choice, so other frameworks/library unfortunately will not help.

In brief, using Prototype.js I am sending a request to a PHP page like this:

```
<input type="button" value="submit by AJAX" onclick="sendRequest();" />
<script>
        function sendRequest(){
            var url = "a_php_page.php";
            var pars = "param={\"some JSON parameters\"}";
            //alert(pars);
            var codeAjax = new Ajax.Request(url, {
                method :'post',
                parameters :pars,
                asynchronous :true,
                onSuccess : function(result){
                    document.write(JSON.stringify(result.responseText));
                }
            });
        }
</script>
```

and the PHP is like this:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type:text/plain');
echo "Hello this is a response!!";
?>
```

I have spent hoursss and yet I cannot get the plain text in the php as a response. I have also tried `JSON.stringify(result)` and all I see is a rather complex object with request and all kinds of text embedded into it and nowhere does it contains "Hello this is a response!"

Here is `JSON.stringify(result)`:

```
{
    "request" : {
        "options" : {
            "method" : "post",
            "asynchronous" : true,
            "contentType" : "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
            "encoding" : "UTF-8",
            "parameters" : "param={\"xxxxxx"]}",
            "evalJSON" : true,
            "evalJS" : true
        },
        "transport" : {
            "statusText" : "",
            "responseText" : "",
            "response" : "",
            "onabort" : null,
            "readyState" : 4,
            "upload" : {
                "onloadstart" : null,
                "onabort" : null,
                "onerror" : null,
                "onload" : null,
                "onprogress" : null
            },
            "onerror" : null,
            "status" : 0,
            "responseXML" : null,
            "onprogress" : null,
            "onload" : null,
            "withCredentials" : false,
            "onloadstart" : null,
            "responseType" : ""
        },
        "url" : "http://xxxxx/xxxxx.php",
        "method" : "post",
        "parameters" : {
            "param" : "{xxxxxx}"
        },
        "body" : "param={xxxxxx}",
        "_complete" : true
    },
    "transport" : {
        "statusText" : "",
        "responseText" : "",
        "response" : "",
        "onabort" : null,
        "readyState" : 4,
        "upload" : {
            "onloadstart" : null,
            "onabort" : null,
            "onerror" : null,
            "onload" : null,
            "onprogress" : null
        },
        "onerror" : null,
        "status" : 0,
        "responseXML" : null,
        "onprogress" : null,
        "onload" : null,
        "withCredentials" : false,
        "onloadstart" : null,
        "responseType" : ""
    },
    "readyState" : 4,
    "status" : 0,
    "statusText" : "",
    "responseText" : "",
    "headerJSON" : null,
    "responseXML" : null,
    "responseJSON" : null
}
```

Comment: after a lot of searching, the problems seem to be in the header, it first says some headers are not allowed, then something else, then eventually it became "Unsafe header X-JSON is not allowed" (or something like that), is this a browser safety feature?

Comment: When you say "a php page", is it on the same domain as the JS making the request, or a different domain?

Answer (score 0):

If you try this, you are not able to get a plain text result from PHP?

```
onSuccess : function(result){
    $('some_id').update(result.responseText);
}
```

result.responseText should just be a string representing everything that was returned from your PHP script back to prototype's Ajax.Request.

Comment: I do not understand `$('some_id').update(result.responseText);` this line, I do understand that $('some_id') is used to retrieve a HTML tag, but as you can see in my PHP code, I am simply doing this: `echo "some text";` as a pure text response

Comment: If from php you echo your text response, then result.responseText should be the response from php in as a string.  $('some_id').update would just set the html of that element to the result, similar to document.write except controlled.  Are you not getting the plain text from result.responseText ?

Comment: no, as shown in the js (the 3rd code block) result.responseText is ""

Comment: The php script looks straight forward  if that is all it is.  I would suggest trying Wireshark to sniff the entire conversation.  In some cases if there is a php parse error, a blank page can be displayed.  When you access the php script from your browser you see the output?

Answer (score 0):

The problem with `document.write()` is it writes out where the script executes but on a callback from an asynchronous action that is... where? I can't be sure so prefer to name an element to write to.

```
function sendRequest() {
    var url = "a_php_page.php";
    new Ajax.Updater('element_id', url, {
        parameters: { param: "some value" },
        insertion: 'bottom'
    });
}
```

Also, I like to pass an object to `parameters` because Prototype can then encode the data in the best way - it is less work & worry for you.

---

When debugging AJAX get something like [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) and watch the network tab, filter by XHR (XmlHttpRequest) and your PHP output will be listed along with the HTTP status code. The status code is important because if it isn't "200" then it's not successful and the page will not update.

The result dump says `"responseText" : ""` several times which suggests no content is being returned at all. Make sure to check the content in Firebug too.

Answer (score 0):

`result.status` is `0`.  This indicates your Ajax request could not contact the server.  Check your URL and network connection.

Interestingly, prototype.js does not treat response code 0 as failure, so you need to test for it:

```
onSuccess : function(result){
    if (result.status == 0) {
        // report error
    } else {
        // true success, handle response
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes it looked strange to me too, since 0 is not really a HTTP response code at all. I later found out in the PHP I have to define a few headers for most of the error messages to go away, but I am stuck with a last error of "Unsafe header X-JSON is not allowed"

Comment: I've written tons of AJAX apps with prototype and PHP and not needed to define any special headers at all.  I have occasionally used X-JSON, but it's certainly not necessary.